# Insert data from CSV into ATHENA AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am using AWS, S3 and Athena to store big file csv, comma delimited, but with newline break inside of them.
So far, i just read that we must used Parquet files in order to insert data correctly.
I am tried to convert csv file to parquet file using Aws Glue Job and it worked correctly, but when i try to insert into database using crawlers data is not correctly inserted.

My AWS Glue job looks like this:

```
import sys
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from awsglue.job import Job


sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)

input_loc = "******* csv files **********"
output_loc = "******* parquet files **********"

inputDyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    connection_type = "s3", 
    connection_options = {
        "paths": [input_loc],}, 
    format = "csv",
    format_options={
    "withHeader": True,
    "separator": ","
    })

outputDF = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame = inputDyf, 
    connection_type = "s3", 
    connection_options = {"path": output_loc 
        }, format = "parquet")
```

AWS Crawler simply read the parquet files from the output_loc and try to insert them into database.

Comment: You could read CSV files too, using Athena. 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory-athena-query.html#:~:text=Athena%20can%20query,values%20(CSV)%20format.

Comment: SerDe CSV does not support embedded line breaks in CSV files, so i am using Parquet